# How to refer to a class with private constructor in a function with generic type parameters?

Tags: typescript, private-constructor

I have a base class and multiple classes that extend that base class which all have a private constructor.

I now want to create a static function that creates new instances of the extending classes. Normally I would have a function header of something like this:

```js
public static createInstance<T extends BaseClass>(clazz: { new(): T }): T
```

When I want to use this function:

```js
createInstance(CustomClass)
```

It causes typescript to spit out this error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof CustomClass' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'new () => CustomClass'.
> Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.

The code actual transpiled code is working perfectly fine.

I know what this error is telling me. But I cannot find a way around this. I've searched a lot and I seem to be very alone with this problem. Is there any way to reference classes with private constructors?

Comment: If the constructor is private, then you cannot construct this class. Conversely, you need *something* that can. Often that's a factory method. So, you might want to receive just a normal function that returns `T`. Or make the constructor non-private, if you intend to only create them with `new`.

Comment: @VLAZ ok I get that. The reason for my try was to reduce redundant code. But that still leaves the question of how to reference a class with a private constructor. Having to add a function that basically does nothing just for being able to reference the class seems a bit dumb :/

Comment: How would you construct the class if it has a private constructor? There should be a reason to make it private - it usually revolves around not wanting to use `new` with it. However, you *have* to provide an alternative way of getting instances of the class, otherwise you've designed an unusable class. (Well, outside of bypassing the type system but this is just a sign that the design is flawed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your issue is surprizingly simple: instead of constraining the generic type parameter `T` to an *instance* type of the `Base` class, constrain it to the *static* (or constructor) side of it via the `typeof Base` type query.

This will ensure that `clazz` will be inferred as the constructor type of the concrete type of `T` instead of the public constructor type (`new (): T`), effectively bypassing the private constructor check while retaining the benefits of the generic constraint:

```js
abstract class Abstract {}

class Base { answer = 42; }

class Custom extends Base {
  private constructor() { super(); }
}

class Unrelated {}

declare function createInstance<T extends typeof Base>(clazz: T): InstanceType<T>;

createInstance(Abstract); // error, OK
createInstance(Base); // OK
createInstance(Custom); // OK
createInstance(Unrelated); // error, OK
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpL1gm)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just used the function signature from the question as the return type of the function is not relevant to the question at hand - however, to avoid confusion, I edited the answer to update the return type to `InstanceType<T>`.

Comment: Ok, now it seems do to the right thing. `let x: Base = createInstance(Base)` doesn't show a warning anymore.