# Type representing a generic class with a private constructor

Tags: typescript, private-constructor

I have a simple function that asserts that an object is an instance of a class. The object and the class are both passed as arguments to the function.

The following is a simplified example that illustrates the issue (without getting into the nitty-gritty of the real code):

```js
function verifyType<T>(instance: unknown, classType:new () => T):instance is T {
    if (!(instance instanceof classType)) throw(`Expecting instance of ${classType.name}`);

    return true;
}
```

([TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwKYCcbAJ4BVsAOqAPLgHwAUMYAzlAIaSoBci4A1mHAO5gA0iCABt6NGviLMwqbogoBKRAF4yiXPObU6jCKkQwaaxAG8AsAChEV-cDkBCKrQZN9Tnaji3ho8YVTzFKAALdB4KAAMAUQAPImhqAHNXbRdPRAASY28xCVQAOjB6AFtUAF9w+QBuCwtrRHRUKBB0JCh0EFRq81Ka8wtswwAxODgTWusIBDp26Dh0BTHLax7u-qmoRGAR5g4uXmVEaVlhuAUutEwcXIotuAETqt7+kTFEACF6dEW6gkxkeigekmThmUDmCzMSysKzq2lgEEEDQBqAh4zqVgaTRahxk70+ZzRiBWK2BdEQACNPjswJweEglHj0HkIEjAQTzBcsHg-BRKegBB90FUgA))

This function works well with most classes:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
    }
}

const foo:unknown = new Foo();
verifyType(foo, Foo);
// OK
```

However, I get compiler errors if the class has a private constructor.

**I understand the reasons for this and it makes sense. A constructor type implies that the calling code could construct the class and a private constructor means this is not permitted.**

However, I can't find an alternative that still allows me to use `instanceof`:

```js
class Bar {
    private constructor() {
    }
    static create() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
const bar:unknown = Bar.create();
verifyType(bar, Foo);
// OK
verifyType(bar, Bar);
// Argument of type 'typeof Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Bar'.
//  Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.
```

#### Trying `T extends typeof Object`

I read [How to refer to a class with private constructor in a function with generic type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66650790/211627)

Based on the answer to that question, I thought that maybe I could use the following:

```js
function verifyType<T extends typeof Object>(instance: unknown, classType:T):instance is InstanceType<T>
```

However, this appears to throw errors because of `Object`'s many static methods:

```js
const foo = new Foo();
verifyType(foo, Foo);
// Argument of type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectConstructor'.
//   Type 'typeof Foo' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectConstructor': getPrototypeOf, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getOwnPropertyNames, create, and 16 more.
```

#### Getting exotic

I tried many variations on `typeof Object` to see if I could both satisfy TypeScript and also ensure runtime correctness, including:

```
function verifyType<T extends Function & Pick<typeof Object, "prototype">>(instance: unknown, classType:T):instance is InstanceType<T>
```

However, while this solved the compile-time errors, it appears to have done so by allowing types that fail at runtime, which is not acceptable:

```
verifyType(bar, ()=>{});
// No compile-time errors
// Runtime Error: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
```

#### Help me `// @ts-expect-error`, you're my only hope

In the end, this might be too niche a use-case and I might have to accept that this edge-case won't be supported any time soon and exempt my code accordingly.

```js
// @ts-expect-error Unfortunately, TS has no type representing a generic class with a private constructor
verifyType(bar, Bar);
```

Comment: what about `T extends Function`? See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAra8W). The only drawback is that `verifyType` would now also accept any functions.

Comment: @TobiasS. Type predicate should be using `InstanceType<T>`. Your example now has `bar` being of type `typeof Bar`.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasS. - I already mentioned that in "Getting exotic". I tried combining that approach with "pick"ing the prototype from the ObjectConstructor, but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm kind of confused why your type guard function can never return `false`.  Looks like you really want an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) instead.  Assuming this is not the point of your question, could you [edit] so that you're either returning `true`/`false` like a regular type guard function or so that you use an assertion function?  That would cut out a potential distraction.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOAKrm) meet your needs?  I've changed to an assertion function, and rather than try to encode "has an `object` prototype", which is really hard to do in the face of `Function`'s awful `any` prototype (ugh, `any`), I just made it so that the runtime blowup is expected (who's going to pass in a non class constructor anyway?) If that works for you I could write up an answer (assuming I don't find anything better). Let me know (and mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me if you do).  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggested approach is to do inference on the `prototype` property of the `classType` parameter, like this:

```
function verifyType<T extends object>(
    instance: unknown,
    classType: Function & { prototype: T }
): asserts instance is T {
    if (!classType.prototype) throw ( 
      `Wait, ${classType.name || "that"} is not a class constructor`);
    if (!(instance instanceof classType)) throw (
      `Expecting instance of ${classType.name}`);
}
```

Generally speaking TypeScript will let you write `x instanceof y` if `y` is of some function type, so hence `Function &`, and then we infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponding to the instance type of `classType` by saying that it's the type of the `prototype` property (TypeScript models class constructor prototypes as being the same type as an instance of the class, even though in practice that is not usually true.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#44181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44181#issuecomment-849844142) and probably others for more information).

In addition to `Function & {protoype: T}` I've made a few changes from your code:

- `verifyType()` is now an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) returning `asserts instance is T` instead of a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) returning `instance is T`.  Type guard functions are supposed to return `true` or `false` and the compiler uses this in its [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  Assertion functions on the other hand don't return any value, they just ensure that the narrowable thing is definitely narrowed.  If you have a type guard function that always returns `true` (and throws otherwise) then you probably want an assertion function instead.
- I've done an explicit check inside the body to see if `classType.prototype` is defined.  TypeScript gives `Function` a `prototype` property of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) instead of the safer [`unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), and this unfortunately makes it almost impossible to detect that a non-constructor like `()=>{}` would throw a runtime error if made the target of `instanceof`. Instead of trying to represent that in the type system, then, I just try to harden `verifyType()`'s implementation against such edge cases.  You might want to check `(!classType.prototype || typeof classType.prototype !== "object")` or any other logic you feel is necessary.

---

Let's test it:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
    }
    a = 1;
}
const foo: unknown = new Foo();
foo.a // error! Object is of type unknown
verifyType(foo, Foo);
foo.a // okay
console.log(foo.a.toFixed(1)) // "1.0"
```

Looks good, the compiler sees that `foo` is a `Foo` after (but not before) `verifyType(foo, Foo)` has been called.

```
class Bar {
    private constructor() {
    }
    static create() {
        return new Bar();
    }
    b = "z"
}
const bar: unknown = Bar.create();
verifyType(bar, Bar);
console.log(bar.b.toUpperCase()); // "Z"
```

Also looks good.  The compiler is happy to allow `verifyType(bar, Bar)` because `Bar` has a `prototype` property of type `Bar` (or so it appears to the compiler) and thus you can then access the `b` property of `Bar`.  It doesn't matter that `Bar` has a `private` constructor.

And finally:

```
const baz: unknown = new Date();
verifyType(baz, () => { }); //  Wait, that is not a class constructor
baz // any
```

We weren't able to flag `verifyType(baz, ()=>{})` at compile time, but at least you get a meaningful runtime error, so the subsequent "narrowing" of `baz` from `unknown` to `any` (ugh, thanks `any`) doesn't affect us.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ANWDw7m4E-QTU7K7zLrdHq3qcyzF9cAAqgQiOgAMIGVBEvbhkYALRHY-EiAng6nOs5bleUQAARZcETXI1N1-Jo60pTh7EQLwV1tOoGiaMYVUYWZ5kWQIViufFCwEX9XykbAgA)

Comment: Very glad to learn about `asserts`. It is really buried in the documentation. There's no mention of it in the [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) docs. I had to go to the [3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) to find any mention of it. Makes me wonder what else I've been missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you also allow any classes that have a `create` method like this:

```
function verifyType<C extends (Function & { create(...args: any[]): unknown }) | (new (...args: any[]) => unknown)>(
  instance: unknown,
  classType: C
): instance is C extends { create(...args: any[]): infer T } ? T : C extends new (...args: any[]) => unknown ? InstanceType<C> : never {
  if (!(instance instanceof classType)) throw `Expecting instance of ${classType.name}`;

  return true;
}
```

While it *does* work, it's not the best since if you have other classes that have differently named factory methods, you'll have to update the function's signature to include these.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36qEN)

---

P.S. If you have an async factory method, simply change `create(): T` to `create(): T | Promise<T>`.

Comment: The return type should actually be `instance is InstanceType<T>` (sorry... my original post failed to represent that for the "exotic" attempts). When your code is corrected, it shows an error for both `<C>` and `<T>`.

Comment: @JDB You're right, and the workaround now is a lot more icky... but at least it works :)

Answer (score 1):

## Thankfully there exists a simple workaround

I ran into the same problem some time ago. You are effectively using the built-in `InstanceType<TClass>` which resolves the instance type *but* comes with the requirement of a public constructor:

`type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = ....`

However the requirement for `InstanceType<TClass>` to have a public constructor is very limiting; It's ok if we only need runtime results, but useless if we want to write open generic types (TS Conditional Types have an abnoxious tendency to mix and match runtime type results with compile-time type results willy-nilly!)

Thankfully we can take full advantage of how the compiler resolves types to the best matching signature and ignore the accessibility modifier to accept private / protected constructors like so:

`type InstanceTypeSpy<TClass> = InstanceType<{ new(): never } & TClass>;`

It works because technically `new(): never` *does* fulfill the expectations of `InstanceType<>` however the compiler (which evaluates and can see all signature match possibilities regardless of access modifier) will choose not to match against `new(): never` to avoid `never` if possible - giving us the real type (or falling back to never if there *actually* does not exist any constructor on `TClass`).

## Trivia

To explain what I mean by runtime vs compile-time types, consider the recently added `Awaited<T>` - it gives us the *runtime type* of awaiting an instance of `T`. Now consider we are writing a generic library that needs to handle `async` / `T = Promise<U>` such that the exact type `T` is not known at library compile time (because `U` is unknown).

*That would be an "open" generic type - Once* `U` *is known it becomes a "closed" generic type.*
*For example* `Map<K,V>` *is an open type, and* `Map<string,object>` *is a closed type.*

In such cases what we need is the *compile-time type*; i.e. if `T = Promise<U>` then we need `U`.

We cannot solve it with `Awaited<T>` because it might not be equal to `U`. If you write some unit-tests and try to assign a value of type `U` to something that expects `Awaited<T>` you will get a compile-error saying it's not assignable.

To understand why, remember that `await` is actually recursive! Ponder what happens if at runtime `U` is of type `Promise<V>`, which would mean our `T` is of type `Promise<Promise<V>>`. At runtime awaiting an instance of type `T` will yield a result of type `V` which is indeed **very** different from a result of type `Promise<V>`. So for an unknown `T` the compiler cannot guarantee correctness of such library code.

*For completeness here is* `Awaited` *made non-recursive*:

```
/**
 * Identical to Awaited<T> except it is NOT recursive, thus giving the compile-time type
 * (rather than the runtime type) which is what you need when writing generics.
 */
export type PromiseResolveType<T> =
  T extends null | undefined ? T : // special case for `null | undefined` when not in `--strictNullChecks` mode
  T extends object & { then(onfulfilled: infer F): any } ? // `await` only unwraps object types with a callable `then`. Non-object types are not unwrapped
    F extends ((value: infer V, ...args: any) => any) ? V : // if the argument to `then` is callable, extracts the unwrapped value
    never : // the argument to `then` was not callable
  T; // non-object or non-thenable
```

Comment: shouldnt those comments be part of the answer?

Comment: @TobiasS. sure, I'll throw them into a trivia section. (one sec...)